# Error when checking input: expected conv2d_1_input to have shape (28, 28, 1) but got array with shape (3, 224, 224)

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

How do I solve it?
codes used by me are displayed below

this is for converting image to vector

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

file = cv2.imread('17316.png')
file = cv2.resize(file, (224, 224))
file = cv2.cvtColor(file, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
file = np.array(file).reshape((1, 3, 224, 224))
print(file.shape[0])
```

this is part of convolution neural network applied by me whoich lead to that error what do I do,how do I solve it please suggest me changes to code so that I can get proper predictions for my dataset?

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3),
                 activation='relu',
                 input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the error message it is obvious that the model is expecting image shape with (28,28,1). So try to resize image before feeding it to the model.

```
file = cv2.imread('17316.png')
file = cv2.resize(file, (28, 28))
file = cv2.cvtColor(file, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
file = file.reshape((-1, 28, 28,1))
```

this will solve the problem.

Comment: error: C:\ci\opencv_1512688052760\work\modules\imgproc\src\resize.cpp:3289: error: (-215) ssize.width > 0 && ssize.height > 0 in function cv::resize

Comment: Your image(file) might be None check that.

Answer (score 0):

Could please post your full code? What is the value of input_shape? I think you should set it to (3, 224, 224). Apparently, your data_format is channels_first and according to [Keras conv2d documentation](https://keras.io/layers/convolutional/#conv2d) the default is channels_last. So, I would suggest to you to use for your first convolutional layer

```
model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size = (3, 3),
                 activation = 'relu',
                 input_shape = (3, 224, 224), 
                 data_format = "channels_first")
```

UPDATE: Based on your code, the following should work, but might not produce the results that you want. You are training on the mnist dataset which expects images that are in 28x28x1 format, so you have to resize like shown in the answer by Mitiku. I hope this helps.

```
import keras
import cv2 
import numpy as np 
from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Flatten 
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D 
from keras import backend as K 

batch_size = 128 
num_classes = 10 
epochs = 1 
img_rows, img_cols = 28, 28
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data() 

if K.image_data_format() == 'channels_first': 
    x_train = x_train.reshape(x_train.shape[0], 1, img_rows, img_cols) 
    x_test = x_test.reshape(x_test.shape[0], 1, img_rows, img_cols) 
    input_shape = (1, img_rows, img_cols) 
else: 
    x_train = x_train.reshape(x_train.shape[0], img_rows, img_cols, 1) 
    x_test = x_test.reshape(x_test.shape[0], img_rows, img_cols, 1) 
    input_shape = (img_rows, img_cols, 1) 
    x_train = x_train.astype('float32')

x_test = x_test.astype('float32') 
x_train /= 255 
x_test /= 255 
print('x_train shape:', x_train.shape) 
print(x_train.shape[0], 'train samples') 
print(x_test.shape[0], 'test samples') 
y_train = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train, num_classes) 
y_test = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test, num_classes)

model = Sequential() 
model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu',\
                 input_shape = input_shape))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu')) 
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))) 
model.add(Dropout(0.25)) 
model.add(Flatten()) 
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu')) 
model.add(Dropout(0.5)) 
model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax')) 
model.compile(loss=keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy, \
              optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adadelta(), \
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=batch_size, epochs=epochs, \
          verbose=1, validation_data=(x_test, y_test)) 
score = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, verbose=0) 

print('Test loss:', score[0]) 
print('Test accuracy:', score[1]) 

file = cv2.imread('17316.png') 
file = cv2.resize(file, (28, 28))
file = cv2.cvtColor(file, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
file = file.reshape((28, 28,1))

model.predict(np.expand_dims(file, axis = 0))
```

UPDATE 2:
You have 10 classes for the mnist dataset. You have a binary classification problem. Your output classifies your image as class 8, which corresponds to the number 7, because the mnist dataset classes are numbers from 0 to 9. We have to know how the classes are encoded - this is problem specific. In this case, to return the number you could do:

```
prediction = model.predict(np.expand_dims(file, axis = 0))
prediction = np.squeeze(prediction)
index = np.where(prediction == 1)[0]
number = (index - 1).item()
print("predicted number for my image: ", number)
```

The last line returns the index of where prediction contains a 1 and as indexing starts at 1, you can subtract one from the index to get the number corresponding to your image.

Comment: import keras
Import cv2
Import numpy as np
from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Flatten
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras import backend as K

batch_size = 128
num_classes = 10
epochs = 1

img_rows, img_cols = 28,28

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()

Comment: if K.image_data_format() == 'channels_first':
    x_train = x_train.reshape(x_train.shape[0], 1, img_rows, img_cols)
    x_test = x_test.reshape(x_test.shape[0], 1, img_rows, img_cols)
    input_shape = (1, img_rows, img_cols)
else:
    x_train = x_train.reshape(x_train.shape[0], img_rows, img_cols, 1)
    x_test = x_test.reshape(x_test.shape[0], img_rows, img_cols, 1)
    input_shape = (img_rows, img_cols, 1)

x_train = x_train.astype('float32')

Comment: x_test = x_test.astype('float32')
x_train /= 255
x_test /= 255
print('x_train shape:', x_train.shape)
print(x_train.shape[0], 'train samples')
print(x_test.shape[0], 'test samples')


y_train = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train, num_classes)
y_test = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test, num_classes)

Comment: model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3),
activation='relu',
input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss=keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy,
optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adadelta(),
metrics=['accuracy'])

Comment: model.fit(x_train, y_train,
batch_size=batch_size,
epochs=epochs,
verbose=1,
validation_data=(x_test, y_test))
score = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, verbose=0)
print('Test loss:', score[0])
print('Test accuracy:', score[1])

file=cv2.imread('17316.png')
file=cv2.resize(file,(224,224))
file=cv2.cvtColor(file, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
file=np.array(file).reshape((3,224,224))
print(file.shape[0])
model.predict(file)

Comment: @rbpeesa: I fixed the formatting problem and updated your code, so that it should work now. Maybe you could delete these comments.

Comment: Ok. Did you try the code? Because I tested the code and I do not get any errors.

Comment: @myself: You asked about how to decode your output. Please see my updated post above (I decided to edit my answer instead of writing into the comments). You asked about (binary?) video classification (comments disappeared). In principle, it is the same: You need a function to decode your output vector.

Comment: I checked it. Ok thanks a lot. How to gain skill like you to solve any problem? How much experience do you have? How did u learn?

Comment: It is not working for all images while squeezing it ,it is showing correct outputs only for few.

Comment: What is the error? The classification is wrong or the code does not work?

Comment: If I want to apply samething to letters dataset available in uci what all should I change and how?